# React Native Touchable Highlight

Tags: react-native

When I press on an `<TouchableHighlight />`, with an `<Image/>` component inside, a white square appears even though I have set `underlayColor` prop's opacity value to 0.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="rgba(255,255,255,0)" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} style={{width: 50, height: 50, position: "absolute", top:15, left: 15, elevation: 10, zIndex: 10}}>
    <Image
        style={{ width: 50, height: 50,}}
          source={backArrow}
    />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

[image: This is how it looks when I press the touchable highlight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could take a different approach, by using `TouchableOpacity` with  `activeOpacity` set to `0` like so:

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} style={{ width: 50, height: 50, position: "absolute", top:15, left: 15, elevation: 10, zIndex: 10}}>
    <Image style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} source={backArrow} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

If I understand your requirements correctly, then you should find this use of the `activeOpacity` prop achieves what you want. For more information on `activeOpacity`, [see this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity#activeopacity)